# javascript new Date(0) class shows 16 hours?

Tags: javascript, date

```
interval = new Date(0);
return interval.getHours();
```

The above returns 16.  I expect it to return 0.  Any pointers?  getMinutes() and getSeconds() return zero as expected.  Thanks!

I am trying to make a timer:

```
function Timer(onUpdate) {
    this.initialTime = 0;
    this.timeStart = null;

    this.onUpdate = onUpdate

    this.getTotalTime = function() {
        timeEnd = new Date();
        diff = timeEnd.getTime() - this.timeStart.getTime();

        return diff + this.initialTime;
    };

    this.formatTime = function() {
        interval = new Date(this.getTotalTime());

        return this.zeroPad(interval.getHours(), 2) + ":" +  this.zeroPad(interval.getMinutes(),2) + ":" + this.zeroPad(interval.getSeconds(),2);
    };

    this.start = function() {
        this.timeStart = new Date();
        this.onUpdate(this.formatTime());
        var timerInstance = this;
        setTimeout(function() { timerInstance.updateTime(); }, 1000);
    };

    this.updateTime = function() {
        this.onUpdate(this.formatTime());
        var timerInstance = this;
        setTimeout(function() { timerInstance.updateTime(); }, 1000);
    };

    this.zeroPad = function(num,count) {
        var numZeropad = num + '';
        while(numZeropad.length < count) {
            numZeropad = "0" + numZeropad;
        }
        return numZeropad;
    }
}
```

It all works fine except for the 16 hour difference.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you initialize the `Date` with 0, it will be set to the beginning of the epoch, Jan 1st 1970 00:00:00 GMT. The hours you get is the localized time offset.

To make a timer, you'd rather start with the current timestamp and calculate the difference to it later on. Remember that timestamps are absolute points in time, not relative.

```
var start = new Date();

// Time is ticking, ticking, ticking...

var end = new Date();

alert(end - start);
```

Or, more concrete:

```
var start = new Date();

setTimeout(function () {
    var end = new Date();
    alert(end - start);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Hmm.. well see my edits to my question.  I may be taking the wrong route

Comment: this is what I did.  But the difference comes out to be zero, and `new Date(0)` reports 16 hours.. I think the problem is that getHours() returns the hour number in the day, not the unix timestamp converted into hours (does that make sense?)

Comment: @Jonah Exactly. In the example above, the difference will most likely be 0, since it's executing immediately. The `time is ticking...` means you need to do something in between and `end` will be created sometime later. Type this example in the console of your browser and you'll see the difference.

Comment: @Jonah `getHours()` indeed returns the **absolute time**, i.e. 4pm, of the timestamp `Dec 31st 1969, 16:00:00` (localized).

Comment: OK so what i needed was a way to convert the milliseconds to hours, minutes and seconds.  Working now.. (getHours() does not work, use a different way) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using getUTCHours() works as expected.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours

Comment: This could use some more fleshing out, according to [answer].