# Javascript Date() function, abnormalities

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, epoch

I recently encountered a problem with unreliable dates in javascript.

Here is an example you can test in your own browser console, to reproduce the problem.

```
s = new Date(0); s.setYear(2015); s
//Thu Dec 31 2015 18:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)

s.setMonth(5); s
//Wed Jul 01 2015 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

s.setMonth(6); s
//Wed Jul 01 2015 18:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

As you can see, set month of 5(june) is the same as 6 (july), both return july.
This is resolved by instead using --  new Date()  instead of new Date(0).

**I would simply like to understand why that occurs.** 
Reiterating, would like to understand WHY.
Can anyone describe this behaviour?

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/front-end-submit-events-off-by-1month?replies=5#post-7059058

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The date is initially **December 31, 2015**.
- `s.setMonth(5)` sets the month to June (months are zero-indexed), so you're setting the date to **June 31, 2015**.
- There is no such date (i.e., June has 30 days), so it rolls over to **July 1, 2015**.
- Setting the month to July with `s.setMonth(6)` does nothing, because the date is already in July.

`new Date()` uses the current date (and today is not the 31st), so this 31-to-1 rollover does not occur.

Comment: perfect, that was what I was wanting to understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Reason for the issue is discussed here: [javascript new Date(0) class shows 16 hours?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604708/javascript-new-date0-class-shows-16-hours)

So, in your case, do not pass 0 in Date();

```js
var s = new Date(); s.setYear(2015);

document.write(s);
document.write("<br/>");

s.setMonth(5);

document.write(s);
document.write("<br/>");


s.setMonth(6); 

document.write(s)
```

Comment: Awesome thank you!  i didn't see that link , it does indeed explain the issue. :)